# MS Excel - how to find names in string

Tags: excel-formula

please, I need help with one formula in MS Excel. I am trying to find names in a string.

My example :
I am looking for :
names in worksheet_Names (A1 : Pierce Bull, A2 : Madonna Hewitt, A3 : Luise Big, etc...)

I am looking in a string in :
worksheet_output (S2 : We tried to contact Pierce Bull several times, S3 : Contract with Madonna Hewitt has been signed), etc....

Requested output - one column, f.e in worksheet_output, column X
for S2 : We tried to contact Pierce Bull several times : req output Pierce Bull
for S3 : Contract with Madonna Hewitt has been signed : req output Madonna Hewitt

Comment: I would expect something to do with these: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx, and http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In worksheet_output cell X2, use this formula and copy down:

```
=INDEX(worksheet_Names!$A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(S2,"*"&worksheet_Names!$A$1:$A$3&"*"),),0))
```

You will need to adjust the `worksheet_Names!$A$1:$A$3` to the actual sheet name and cell range